# Filter dictionary based on the values in second dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

The two list of dictionaries are class1 and class2 as mentioned below.

```
class1 =[{'name':3450,'val':0.3298},{'name':2250,'val':0.3278},{'name':4380,'val':0.38732},{'name':8450,'val':0.27824}]

class2 =[{'name':2250,'cutoff':0.3},{'name':3450,'cutoff':0.6},{'name':8450,'cutoff':0.9},{'name':4380,'cutoff':0.2}]
```

So I want create a 3rd dictionary out of above 2 dictionaries as filteredClasses in such a way that

if the 'val' in the class1 > (greater than) 'cutoff' in the class2 then I want to add it to list of dictionaries which are class1 as shown below.

```
filteredClasses =[{'name':2250,'val':0.3278},{'name':4380,'val':0.38732}]
```

Please help me to write an efficient code for this. I am new to programming and new to python and its data types, I tried the following

```
for n in class1:
  if n['name'] == class2['name']:
      filteredClasses = [ class1['val'] > class2['cutoff'] ]
```

I know I am illogical in the above code,But I think you got my point what I trying to tell. Please help me fixing it.

Comment: class1 and class2 are not dictionaries. They are lists of dictionaries.

Comment: It looks like you got a bunch of answers. If one solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the green checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: appriciate it, I did that, I am new to Stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filteredclass = [x for x in class1 if x['val'] > [y for y in class2 if x['name'] == y['name']][0]['cutoff']]
```

### Result

```
>>> [x for x in class1 if x['val'] > [y for y in class2 if x['name'] == y['name']][0]['cutoff']]

[{'name': 2250, 'val': 0.3278}, {'name': 4380, 'val': 0.38732}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 filtered=[ [v['name'], k['val']] for k,v in zip(class1,class2) if k['val'] > v['cutoff']  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a loop that will accomplish this task, hope this helps!

```
for i in class1:
    for j in class2:
        if i['name'] == j['name']:
            try:
                if i['val'] > j['cutoff']:
                    if i not in filtered:
                        filtered.append(i)
            except TypeError:
                pass

print(filtered)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 filer.py 
> [{'name': 2250, 'val': 0.3278}, {'name': 4380, 'val': 0.38732}]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, Pandas offers an efficient solution. This works as lists of dictionaries can be fed directly to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. The reverse process can be applied via `to_dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

# read lists of dictionaries into a dataframe and series
df = pd.DataFrame(class1)
s = pd.DataFrame(class2).set_index('name')['cutoff']

# use Boolean filtering on dataframe
res = df[df['val'] > df['name'].map(s)]

# extract list of dictionaries for desired result
print(res.to_dict('records'))

[{'name': 2250.0, 'val': 0.3278},
 {'name': 4380.0, 'val': 0.38732}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of `vash_the_stampede` one

```
filteredClasses = [each for each in class1 for each2 in class2 if each["name"] == each2["name"] and each["val"] > each2["cutoff"]] 
# O(len(class1)*len(class2))
```